# Do STP 802.1D support Uplink Fast, Backbone Fast and Port Fast?

Tags: spanning-tree

Do STP 802.1D support Uplink Fast, Backbone Fast and Port Fast ?
Aren't these features cisco proprietary ?
Is IEEE later add these feature into 802.1D ?
If so, Why are they not called Alternate Port, Proposal Agreement and Edge Port just like RSTP ?

Comment: Cisco has often come up with new protocols, feature, or enhancements, but the industry was wary of Cisco influence. Often the ideas that Cisco used were later adopted in, but not the Cisco versions. A big example is HSRP where Cisco actually submitted it as an RFC, but the industry created VRRP, and few other companies implemented HSRP. There are many such examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the obsolete 802.1D STP protocol, implementations may or may not allow adminstrative configuration of edge ports. The protocol itself did not specifically allow for those configurations.

RSTP included various optimizations. One of them allows for explicit configuration of *edge ports*, ie. ports that connect a single entity:

> A Bridge Port attached to a LAN that has no other Bridges attached to
> it may be administratively configured as an Edge Port. RSTP monitors
> the LAN to ensure that no other Bridges are connected, and may be
> configured to automatically detect an Edge Port. Each Edge Port
> transitions directly to the Forwarding Port State, since there is no
> possibility of it participating in a loop.

Other terms for that feature are proprietary.

An Alternate Port is something else: *An Alternate Port offers an
alternate path in the direction of the Root Bridge to that provided by the Bridge’s own Root Port, [...]*

You can get IEEE 802 standards from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68 (free after registration).